# Using a namespaced class as a View Composer in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

I have a simple setup where I need to show a bit of data universally across my app, in the header of my site. To do so, I have created a `ComposerServiceProvider` class and a `HeaderComposer` class to delegate this responsibility, as seen below:

## ComposerServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $this->app->view->composer('templates.header', 'HeaderComposer');
    }
}
```

## HeaderComposer

```
class HeaderComposer {
    public function compose($view) {

        Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($q) {
            print_r($q);
        });

        $view->with('nearbyMissions', array(
            'past' => Mission::remember(60, 'previousMissions')->previousMissions(3)->get(),
            'future' => Mission::remember(60, 'nextMissions')->nextMissions(3)->get()
        ));
    }
}
```

Previously, these classes were not namespaced, but I have now decided to namespace each of them as a good practice, by prepending the files with:

```
namespace MyProject\Composers;
```

However, this has broken my application as some part of my project can no longer resolve my composer classes. None of my pages work because they all use a templated header view which uses my `HeaderComposer`:

```
Class HeaderComposer does not exist (View: H:\myproject\app\views\templates\main.blade.php)
```

Where am I meant to declare the `use` statements for my class? In my view? (Which doesn't seem right). Somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->app->view->composer('templates.header', 'MyProject\Composers\ HeaderComposer');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just namespaced your class, then you have to update your composer binding:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->view->composer('templates.header', 'MyProject\Composers\HeaderComposer');
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, I thought that would've been relative to the current class. Makes sense though. Cheers.